# DVI-I crossover screen problem

Tags: graphics, display

I anticipate that I will be a little long-winded so that I can be as clear and detailed as possible.

I have this crossover 27QW LED AH-IPS Monitor that is giving me quite a bit of trouble.
I can't get anything on the screen and it is not clear why , I have also tried different types of cables but it doesn't depend on the cables.

My Xubuntu ( but also windows ) detect the monitor but can not use it , I have used <> and multiple commands found on the internet but nothing I have not solved.

Below I attach a few screens to give you a better understanding of what is going on :

This is what I see from the settings -->screen
Trying to activate that screen with the "switch" at the top I still can't get anything done

[image]

While this is what I get with xrandr

[image]

Giving the commands to add the " modes " however I can not get anything .

I experience this problem on any computer , laptop and fixed , that I have tried with , that is why I deduced that it is the monitor.

One very curious thing is that the monitor as mentioned above never works except in GRUB , as you can see below.

[image]

With the command --> lshw -c display I get returned :
-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 0e
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:95 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3050(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff

the monitor has always worked on windows but connected to a dedicated graphics card.  Now I would like to make it work on my laptop which has AMD graphics card integrated ( lenovo ideapad 5 with ryzen 5 5500u ) . Also tried it on other pc , same result

Thank you in advance for the answers

Comment: Have you checked that your video card has enough RAM to handle the external screen?  It maybe you can only use the external display if you lower the video resolution of your primary screen, thus the video card has RAM enough to enable the external display to be used (*or you attach lower-resolution screen(s)*).  ie. your issue maybe video card related, thus why you're having the same issue in both Windows & Xubuntu.

Comment: I reduced the screen resolution of the notebook , but the screen (crossover) still remains off. 

Unfortunately, the system doesn't seem to detect it properly . in fact, I can't change the (crossover) screen settings, so I can't even disable the notebook's main screen and only turn on the (crossover)

Comment: How is it connected?